# Explanation as to why the inverse image of a closed set, under a continuous function, is closed.

Tags: real-analysis

The fact that the inverse image of a closed set, under a continuous function, is closed seems strange to me. What if the function that maps the sets is given as:
$$f(x)=0$$
This is a continuous function, but no matter what set it maps, the image will be the set $\{0\}$ which is closed no matter what set It mapped. I am obviously wrong since the statement is known to be true, but I am not sure why I am wrong. Can someone explain why my reasoning is flawed?

I thought it might be because the function had to be in terms of the elements in the set. Just a guess?

Comment: If $A$ is any closed subset of $\Bbb R$, then either $0\in A$, in which case $f^{-1}[A]=\Bbb R$, or $0\notin A$, in which case $f^{-1}[A]=\varnothing$. Both $\Bbb R$ and $\varnothing$ are closed sets in $\Bbb R$, so $f$ is continuous. I’m not sure where you’re having difficulty with this.

Comment: You seem to make a confusion between image and pre-image. A function is continuous is the *preimage* of every closed set is closed... There is nothing in the definition about what has to be the image of any set.

Comment: Suppose $A$ is the domain of $f$, and $f$ is the constant zero function. Then the preimage of $\{ 0 \}$ is indeed $A$. You say that $A$ might not be closed, but the fact is that $A$ is a closed subset of $A$ itself.

Comment: @Crostful The statement A is a closed subset of itself seems odd to me. How is A a closed set?

Comment: Would A have all properties of a closed set? Even if f(x) is defined for all x, in which case the domain A is open.

Comment: Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_topology